# Cannot restore Object from Instance state: parsing error

Tags: android, parsing, serialization

I am trying to restore an array of Objects from a `savedInstanceState`. I added each one to the `Bundle` individually here: (rhythm is the array of Objects)

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    outState.putInt("numParts",rhythm.length);
    for(int index = 0;index<rhythm.length;++index){
        outState.putSerializable(""+index,rhythm[index].beat);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

When the `onRestoreInstanceState()` method is called, I try to assign my `rhythm` array with the Objects from the Instance State here: (it isn't null)

```
@Override 
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    rhythm = new Part[savedInstanceState.getInt("numParts")];
    for(int index = 0; index<rhythm.length;++index){
         Object middleMan =savedInstanceState.getSerializable(""+index);
         if(middleMan==null){
             System.out.println("It's null...");
         }
    rhythm[index]=(Part) middleMan;
    }
}
```

It throws a `ClassCastException` when I parse to a `Part` every time. Part implements `Serializable`. Why is it not allowing me to parse? Will I need to do custom serialization? 
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I just did it as the whole array and it worked... I don't really know why, but it did. Thanks for giving me the idea to just pass the whole array. @Error 454

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that Part is a type that you have created?  So instead of treating Part as an array

```
rhythm = new Part[savedInstanceState.getInt("numParts")];
```

You want to instantiate a new Part object like so:

```
rhythm = new Part(savedInstanceState.getInt("numParts"));
```

Other assumptions:

1. rhythm is a member variable
2. The constructor for Part takes a single integer

Comment: no, rhythm is an array that holds Parts. It I stored and retrieved that int so I could initialize an array with the correct amount of elements. The Parts are then pulled out of the bundle and added to the  rhythm array with a for loop... Should I have just serialized the whole array? How would I do that?